# How to have a yeast bread dough rise in a cool space

Tags: bread

I saw an answer to a similar question and a gentleman named Joe said to use a radiator. I would relly appreciate more information about this.
Thank you

Comment: The duplicate should give you a whole range of options. Using a radiator simply means to place the dough on or near a radiator (don’t overheat, else you will kill your yeast).

Comment: Put it in a bowl in the microwave, heat up a mug of water in the kettle and put it in the microwave with the door closed. Sealing in the steam will help it rise.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! My house is well over 100, and my interest was peaked when I saw the post about using the radiators,as mine are original to my very chilly house.